# Ruby - Get the past x months from a giving date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

How can I get the past x months from a giving date?

so for instance, if the date is **2023-01-04**, and I want the past 3 months *(including the current date)*, it would give me an `array` of:

```
[
'2023-01-01',
'2022-12-01',
'2022-11-01'
]
```

I tried with:

```
current_month = Date.today.month
3.downto(1).map { |n| Date.parse(DateTime::MONTHNAMES.drop(1)[(current_month - n) % 12]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }
```

It worked fine when the year wasn't over and it only gives the months for that giving year and for the new year, it outputs completely wrong dates.

*PS: I have seen a few solutions but nothing works*

Comment: If you're using Rails you have [`advance`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.1/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-advance) which can roll forward (or back, it's just negative values) any arbitrary period of time.

Comment: thanks @tadman, yes I use Rails, but haven't used `advance` before. Would you please give me an example to get the past months

Comment: `advance(months: -1)` etc. I'm sure you can put it together from there. Consider: `3.times.map do |n|` and use `n`.

Comment: `Date.today << 1` will subtract a month. (This is plain Ruby).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use methods like `beginning_of_month` and Rails handles simple date math quite easily:

edit: using the OP's original form:

```
2.downto(0).map {|i| Date.today.beginning_of_month - (i).months}
```

As tadman points out this is cleaner. They would just have to make the logical shift of "I want three months" = 3 - 1 down to 0 somewhere else in code.

```
my_dates = (1..3).map {|i| Date.today.beginning_of_month - (i - 1).months}

#=> [Sun, 01 Jan 2023, Thu, 01 Dec 2022, Tue, 01 Nov 2022]
```

That output looks weird because the console is showing date objects, so they should be a different color than the square brackets and the comma between the dates.

Comment: I'm with you most of the way, but using a 1..3 range and then offsetting back by 1 seems pointless. Why not 0..2, or in other words, `3.times`?

Comment: I was just taking the OP's data of 1..3 as something I couldn't mess with. If they want to do that transformation first then great. But this takes exactly the input they gave me and gave the correct output.

Comment: They could substitute any form of 1...3 or 3...1 or 3.downto(1) or use 2..0 or 2.downto(0).

Comment: Fair enough, it just looks out of place when expressed like this.

Comment: I'd probably wrap it in a method and the submitted number desired would get decremented one then passed into the code inside the method.

Comment: do'h!  I use the form of `#.times` so many other places and it didn't even occur to me until I reread your comment. Even better.

Answer (score 2):

This merely implements @steenslag's comment on the question.

```
require 'date'

def prev_dates(date_str, nbr_months)
  first_date = DateTime.strptime(date_str[0,7], '%Y-%m')
  nbr_months.times.with_object([]) do |i,arr|
    arr << (first_date << i).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  end
end
```

```
prev_dates('2023-01-04', 3)
  #=>["2023-01-01", "2022-12-01", "2022-11-01"]
prev_dates('2023-01-04', 1)
  #=> ["2023-01-01", "2022-12-01", "2022-11-01"]
```

See [DateTime::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime), [Date#<<](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3C) and [Date#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime).